# como sacar el id de una tabla html para hacer una consulta después con php

Tags: php, html

espero em puedan ayudar, tengo el siguiente codigo el cual, al realizar la consulta de todos los registros de una tabla me lo realiza bien, y me crea dos botones al final de cada fila, los cuales son para modificar y eliminar el registro, lo que quiero hacer es que al momento de presionar el boton de modificar, me tome toda la fila de ese registro y me cree un formulario para modificar el registro, pero que el formulario contenga en cada input el valor que se va a modificar. espero me haya dado a entender y me puedan ayudar por favor

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
$name = $_POST['name'];
}?>
<section class="container" style="float:rigth; align: right;">
      <div class="row ">
          <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2"></div>   
          <form method="post" class="form-signin col-4" > 

              <p class="h3 mb-3 font-weight-normal" >Ingresa tu RFC para acceder a tus vacantes</p>   
              <input  type="text" name="name" class="form-control" placeholder="RFC" required>
              <div class="space-20"></div>

  <button class="btn btn-lg button-disponibilidad btn-block" type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit Form">Ver mis Vacantes</button>

          </form>   
          <div class="col-4"></div> 
     </div>
   </section>


<div class="space-30"></div>
<table class="table">
<thead class="thead-dark">
<tr>
    <th>id_vacante</td>
        <th>Empresa que solicita vacante</th>
        <th>Puesto</th>
        <th>Perfil</th>
        <th>Experiencia</th>    
        <th>Idiomas</th>    
        <th>Nombre (contacto)</th>  
        <th>Telefono</th>   
        <th>Correo</th> 
        <th>Fecha de publicasión</th>   
</tr>
</thead>
<?php 
    $sql="SELECT * from tvacantes WHERE rfc='$name' ";
    $result=mysqli_query($conexion,$sql);
    while($mostrar=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
     ?>
<tbody>
<form method="POST" action="subirvacante.php" >
<tr>
        <th id="llave"><?php echo $mostrar['id_vac'] ?></th>
        <th><?php echo $mostrar['emp_vac'] ?></th>
        <th><?php echo $mostrar['puesto'] ?></th>
        <th><?php echo $mostrar['Perfil_puesto'] ?></th>
        <th><?php echo $mostrar['expe'] ?></th>
        <th><?php echo $mostrar['idioma_add'] ?></th>
        <th><?php echo $mostrar['nom'] ?></th>
        <th><?php echo $mostrar['tel'] ?></th>
        <th><?php echo $mostrar['correo'] ?></th>
        <th><?php echo $mostrar['add_date'] ?></th>
        <th>  <a > <button type='submit' class='btn btn-success' id="modificar">Modificar</button> </a> </th>
        <th>  <a> <button type='button' class='btn btn-danger'>Elimiar</button> </a> </th>


    </tr>
    </form>
<?php 
}
 ?>

 <section id="modificacion">

 </section>
```

Comment: No entiendo bien tu pregunta. Por lo que se ve traes ciertos datos de la base de datos y los muestras en una tabla, luego hay dos botones y dices que quieres que si se pulsa `Modificar` te muestre ¿un formulario, aparte de la tabla? con los datos de ese registro. Pregunto: ¿dónde tienes los datos para mostrarlos? No me digas que vas a ir de nuevo a buscarlos a la base de datos, cuando acabas de traerlos en una consulta. Entonces, ¿dónde están los datos? Si no entendí bien el asunto entonces aclara mejor el problema.

Comment: pues ya los tengo en la tabla, pero no se como pasarlos a un formulario para que cuando lo quieran modificar, sepan los valores que ya existen en ese campo

Comment: o igual si se puede que al presionar el botón de modificar en la misma tabla se puedan modificar pues también estaría bien, pero no se como se hace

Comment: Puedes poner elementos `input` dentro de la tabla con los valores cargados. Pero se requiere en ese caso una lógica refinada pero muy sencilla: desactivas de entrada los botones `Editar` o mejor no los muestras, *escuchas* por JS si hay cambio en algún input y entonces activas y/o muestras el botón `Editar` para esa fila. O se pueden escuchar cambios globales, o sea permitir modificar varias filas y lanzar desde un botón general la actualización de esas filas que fueron modificadas.

Comment: ya puse inputs, pero me aparecen demasiado grandes, porque algunos campos de la tabla tienen mucho texto y no alcanzan a caber en la pantalla

Comment: Eso no significa que tengas que renunciar a ello. La ventaja es que un `input` es editable, mientras que una tabla no. Para los textos grandes puedes usar un `textfield` y puedes controlar el tamaño por CSS para que te muestre hacia abajo ese contenido muy ancho. O, puedes mostrar sólo parte del texto y el contenido completo cuando activas esa fila para editar. Es cuestión de mirar más ampliamente sabiendo que casi todo es posible cuando usas la herramienta correcta.

Comment: intentaré eso amigo, muchas gracias

Comment: Puedes hacer uso de Tabledit un plugin para DataTables que te permitirá editar en línea la tabla. https://markcell.github.io/jquery-tabledit/